# Unable to connect to O365 using SharePoint Online Management

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365

I am trying to connect to my site using SharePoint Online Management Shell. But it isn't connecting. The following error is being displayed.

[image]

What could be the possible reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your cmdlet, There is a **space** between `-` and `URL` parameter! so you got this error

> A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts arguments -

**The cmdlet**

```
Connect-SPOService -Url https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com -credential admin@contoso.com
```

For more details check [Connect-SPOService](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161392.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)